# HTML form within PHP tags

Tags: php, html

I want to make a form that submits data from user input into a database. However, when making the form, it does not appear in the browser.

Here is the code.

```
echo '<form name="submit" method="post" action="reservation_confirm.php">';
echo '<Confirm: <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="confirm">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Remove `<` from Confirm, you're trying to parse it as HTML.

Comment: or if you really want the `<` to show before Confirm then `echo '&gt;Confirm: ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a less-than sign `<` to many.

Change:

```
echo '<Confirm: <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="confirm">';
//----^ remove
```

To:

```
echo 'Confirm: <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="confirm">';
```

Comment: Thanks. I've realised that I've made some silly mistakes. I relatively new to coding so thank you for you your help.

Comment: @Blackman123 If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of less sign on your second line. It is considered HTML opening tag.
Try this:

```
echo '<form name="submit" method="post" action="reservation_confirm.php">';
echo '&#60;Confirm: <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="confirm">';
echo '</form>';
```

Or simply remove it.